# Can I use multiple splice methods within the same function? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, splice

I am making a program that shuffles some cards in a deck but not all.  The values that I want to shuffle are stored in an array toBeShuffled.  I have multiple for loops running within my function and each one is selecting elements from the array without replacement.  However, it seems as though each time a new for loop runs the toBeShuffled array is repopulated with the elements the previous for loops removed.

```
function redeal() {
  shuffleCards();
  for(let a=rowholder1; a<=12;a++){
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*toBeShuffled.length);
    cards[a].style.order = toBeShuffled.splice(randomPos,1);
  }
  for(let b=rowholder2; b<=25;b++){
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*toBeShuffled.length);
    cards[b].style.order = toBeShuffled.splice(randomPos,1);
  }
  for(let c=rowholder2; c<=38;c++){
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*toBeShuffled.length);
    cards[c].style.order = toBeShuffled.splice(randomPos,1);
  }
  for(let d=rowholder2; d<=51;d++){
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*toBeShuffled.length);
    cards[d].style.order = toBeShuffled.splice(randomPos,1);
  }
}

function shuffleCards() {
  for(let i=0; i<13;i++) {
    if(cards[i].style.order != cards[i+1].style.order - 1) {
      rowholder1 = i+1;
      for(let j=i+1;j<14;j++){
      toBeShuffled.push(j);
    }break;
    }
  }
  for(let k=13; k<26;k++) {
    if(cards[k].style.order != cards[k+1].style.order - 1) {
      rowholder2 = k+1;
      for(let j=k+2;j<28;j++){
        toBeShuffled.push(j)
    }break;
  }
}
  for(let l=26; l<39;l++) {
    if(cards[l].style.order != cards[l+1].style.order - 1) {
      rowholder3 = l+1;
      for(let j=l+3;j<42;j++){
        toBeShuffled.push(j)
    }break;
  }
}
  for(let m=39; m<52;m++) {
    if(cards[m].style.order != cards[m+1].style.order - 1) {
      rowholder4 = m+1;
      for(let j=m+4;j<56;j++){
        toBeShuffled.push(j)
    } return toBeShuffled;    
  }
}
}
```

The reason I am using multiple for loops is because there are some indices in cards which I do no want to reassign an order.

Comment: The easiest way to know what's going on is to add `console.log(toBeSuffled)` after each loop finishes.

Comment: please include a complete code sample, including things your function references